# How do you catch sigtrap so your malware will still run while being debugged?

Tags: debugging

I have written a small shellcode but it is trapped at `execve()` by the debugger if it is attached. Can this be bypassed? Note that I can add any instructions to my shellcode, but I don't have root privileges.